# VectorDrawable not showing or drawed wrong

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have 5 `vectorDrawables`, where 3 of them is generated from an PSD given to me from [google](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/graphics).

Two of them is showing correctly (both from the generated vector from PSD), but the other two is not working at all, when running on API 21, but works fine on API 26, 27.

[image]

Two two vectors not showing looks like this

[image]

The two ImageButton's looks like this: ([full XML file](https://gist.github.com/uruloke/05191c5ad0ba366efaa96edd5ccdbe61))

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/multiplayerButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/button_multiplayer_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/startButton" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/achievementButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/button_achievements_icon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/multiplayerButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/highscoreButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/multiplayerButton" />
```

The sword `vector` looks this way

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="512"
android:viewportWidth="512" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@color/menu_buttons" android:name="ic multiplayer"
    android:pathData="m468.9 41.5 -73.1 15.5 -127.2 139.4 43.1 47.3 141.6 -129.2 15.5 -73.1zm-267.5 228.6 -55.8 61.2 -28.7 -28.7 -28.8 28.7 20 20 -69.5 69.5 51.6 51.6 69.4 -69.5 19.4 19.3 28.7 -28.7 -28.7 -28.7 63 -57.5 -40.7 -37.2zm-158.4 -228.6 15.6 73.1 274.3 250.3 -28.7 28.7 28.8 28.8 19.3 -19.3 69.5 69.5 51.6 -51.6 -69.4 -69.5 20 -20 -28.8 -28.7 -28.7 28.7 -250.3 -274.3 -73.1 -15.5z"/>
```

And the ribbon `vector` `xml` file looks like this

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="512"
android:viewportWidth="512" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@color/menu_buttons" android:name="ic achievements"
    android:pathData="m256.3 343.9 47.2 21.9 23 -34.2 55.3 104 -69.8 68.3 -55.7 -160zm-0.7 0 -47.2 21.9 -22.9 -34.2 -55.3 104 69.8 68.3 55.7 -160zm0.3 -296.5 43.1 -20 27.4 38.9 47.3 4.2 4.2 47.4 38.9 27.3 -20 43.1 20 43.1 -38.9 27.4 -4.2 47.3 -47.3 4.2 -27.4 38.9 -43.1 -20 -43.1 20 -27.4 -38.9 -47.3 -4.2 -4.2 -47.3 -38.9 -27.4 20 -43.1 -20 -43.1 38.9 -27.3 4.2 -47.4 47.3 -4.2 27.4 -38.9 43.1 20zm0.2 48.5c-50.8 0 -92.1 41.2 -92.1 92c0 50.9 41.2 92.1 92.1 92.1c50.8 0 92 -41.2 92 -92.1c0 -50.8 -41.2 -92 -92 -92z"/>
```

Where the variable `menu_buttons` is defined to `#FFC107`, in `colors.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`VectorDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) added in API level 21.

> Support Library 23.2 or higher provides full support to Vector
>   Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables on devices running Android 5.0
>   (API level 21) or lower.

You should use

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector_image"
```

You need to add **`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`** to your `build.gradle` file:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

**FYI**

> **`app:srcCompat`** attribute to reference vector drawables as well as any
>   other drawable available to **android:src**.

Comment: But vectors was added in API21 right? So it should work without using srcCompat, or am I misunderstanding something? Also why is some of the icons showing?

Comment: It works when using srcCompat, but I still don't get why it doesn't work in API 21 when just using src.

Comment: Because AppCompat version of VectorDrawables fixes bugs that were on older API.
That's why it's better to use AppCompat version of every API.